# Python syntax highlighting on Codeplex

Tags: python, syntax-highlight, codeplex

My .py files in a Codeplex (hg-based) repository don't show up with the nice syntax highlighting as they do for C and C++ when I browse the code on the web. Is there a way to change the syntax highlighting settings in Codeplex?

Comment: Yes, there is a way, but you need to read this long post and then figure out how compilers work. http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2007/06/rich-programmer-food.html
A smart lad with a dragon book should be able to do it in 1-2 weeks.

Comment: Well, even if I __were__ to write my own syntax parser (probably not gonna happen), how would I be able to do syntax highlighting on the Codeplex website? Cross-site Javascripting? Isn't there like an option somewhere on Codeplex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This post](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/codeplex/codeplex-syntax-highlighting) from a couple years ago when they first added syntax highlighting says that they'll add other languages by request.

> We plan to add more languages based on your requests. Please create an issue in the CodePlex Issue Tracker to request syntax highlighting for additional languages, or to report any problems you find with the current languages.

I found a ticket in the Issue Tracker for this already, which you can find [here](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=codeplex).  Voting it up and adding a comment would probably help the cause.